# Angular2 get url query parameters

Tags: url, angular, parameters, routes

I'm setting up a Facebook registration for my Angular2 web app.
Once the application accepted via Facebook (after being redirected to the Facebook authorization page), it redirect to my webapp with the token and code as url params:

```
http://localhost:55976/?#access_token=MY_ACCESS_TOKEN&code=MY_CODE
```

But once the page is loaded, the params are removed. The url become:

```
http://localhost:55976/
```

How can I extract the parameters (access_token and code) before they are removed?
My routing configuration contains:

```
{ path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
{ path: 'login/:access_token/:code', component: LoginComponent },
```

**EDIT:**

Here is how I redirect to facebook in my login.component:
html:

```
<a class="btn btn-social btn-facebook socialaccount_provider facebook" title="Facebook" href="#" (click)="login_facebook()">
    <span class="fa fa-facebook"></span> <span style="padding-left:25px">Sign in with Facebook</span>
</a>
```

Typescript:

```
login_facebook() {
    let url = 'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?'+
        'client_id=my_client_id' +
        '&redirect_uri=' + encodeURIComponent('http://localhost:55976/#/login/') +
        '&response_type=code%20token';
    console.log(url);
    window.location.href = url;
}
```

The facebook api redirect to http://localhost:55976/#/login/, this is where I try to get the access_token and code parameters.

**EDIT 2:**

If I remove the sharp in the redirect url, facebook redirect me to the good URL, but without the sharp, angular cannot resolve the url.

Before removing '#':

```
redirect_uri: http://localhost:55976/#/login/
facebook return: http://localhost:55976/?#access_token=MY_ACCESS_TOKEN&code=MY_CODE
```

After removing '#':

```
redirect_uri: http://localhost:55976/login/
facebook return: http://localhost:55976/login/?#access_token=MY_ACCESS_TOKEN&code=MY_CODE
```

That mean that the problem comes from the sharp. But without the sharp, angular returns HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is my final working code:

Imports:

```
import { Router, NavigationCancel } from '@angular/router';
import { URLSearchParams, } from '@angular/http';
```

Constructor:

```
 constructor(public router: Router) {
    router.events.subscribe(s => {
      if (s instanceof NavigationCancel) {
        let params = new URLSearchParams(s.url.split('#')[1]);
        let access_token = params.get('access_token');
        let code = params.get('code');
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: Which location strategy are you using? I also have the problem that you have in the above comment: that the hash fragment is removed before I can access it.. did you manage this to work with hashlocationstrategy or it only works with html5 pathlocationstrategy?

Comment: I'm using html5 pathlocationstrategy. I'm not sure but i think it only works with this strategy.

Comment: Yep, I confirm, this only works with the pathlocationstrategy

Comment: +1 for correct answer. I usually hold myself from ranting but this is the right answer I suppose and yeah, imagine that ... in pure JS it takes one row and in Angular it takes imports, subscribes, etc. Too much to do very little.

Answer (score 29):

You're looking for [query parameters](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#optional-route-parameters) from `ActivatedRoute`.

To receive them, you could put them into your component's `OnInit` function like this:

```
private accesstoken;
private code;

constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

ngOnInit() {
  // Capture the access token and code
  this.route
      .queryParams
      .subscribe(params => {
          this.accesstoken = params['#access_token'];
          this.code = params['code'];
      });

  // do something with this.code and this.accesstoken
}
```

There's more examples in the link I put above. You *may* have problems with angular because the router also identifies fragments, which start with the #... If angular *does* identify it as a fragment, then you can just subscribe to the fragment observable from `ActivatedRoute` and do it that way.

I'm not sure if you're being redirected. If you are, the could look into using the `preserveQueryParams` navigation option, something like this.

```
this.router.navigate([redirect], {preserveQueryParams: true});
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The params are still empty. I've tried with fragment observable from ActivatedRoute but it doesn't change anything. I'm not being redirected. The redirection is made by the facebook api. I have updated the main post to add more details.

Comment: Hmmm. To me, it seems like if the problem might be that facebook is redirecting to http://localhost:55976/?#access_token=MY_ACCESS_TOKEN&code=MY_CODE while you want to redirect to http://localhost:55976/#/login/?access_token=MY_ACCESS_TOKEN&code=MY_CODE. Maybe facebook is redirecting to the wrong component?

Comment: Yes you are right, the problem seems to comes from the facebook redirection. I have updated my post. The problem know is the redirection without the '#'.

Comment: You can change angular2 to work without the # by using the `PathLocationStrategy` instead of `HashLocationStrategy`. However the `PathLocationStrategy` is already the default in angular2 so you're probably overriding it somewhere. What does your main module look like where you're providing your routes? See [here for more info](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#browser-url-styles).

Comment: You are right, PathLocatinoStrategy was set to HashLocationStrategy. But when I set it to PathLocationStrategy, I get 404 errors every time I try to access a page with url (instead of navigating).

Comment: I have fixed my 404 error but now, when the login page is reached, the hash fragment is removed before I can access it. Any idea?

Answer (score 4):

Using JavaScript:

```
(new URL(location)).searchParams.get("parameter_name")
```

Comment: this is almost perfect for me. but I'm getting this error when typescript is building: Argument of type 'Location' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'

Comment: URL constructor expects a string as first parameter but location is a [Location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location). 
`new URL(location.href)` will work.

Comment: For you guys having timing headaches in Observables.

Answer (score 2):

```
getQueryParams( locationSearch: string):any {
    let params = {};
    if( locationSearch ) {
        locationSearch = locationSearch.split('?')[1];
        let splited = locationSearch.split('&');
        for( let i = 0; i < splited.length; i++ ) {
            let propName = splited[i].split('=')[0];
            let propValue = splited[i].split('=')[1];
            params[propName] = propValue;
        }
    }

    return params;
}

let q = getQueryParams( location.search );
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router'; 

constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

/** usage in the method */
let projectId = this.route.snapshot.queryParams.projectId;
```

Answer (score 0):

Check my answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47154085/how-to-retrieve-parameters-from-url-fragment-in-angular-application/54945281#54945281) post.

Use `window.location.hash` to access to all parameters starting from #.
Or you can use `window.location.href` to access full URL.
To get the token you can use `window.location.hash.match(/#access_token=([^&]+)/)[1]`.

Note: If you are using TypeScript then you'd need to import window in your component.

```
declare let window;
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
import { Params, Router } from '@angular/router';


     constructor(private router: Router) {
            
            this.route.params.forEach((params: Params) => {
            //here you can get your params
            let param = params['parameterName'];
       

            })
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The this.route.params variable is empty. When I try to log it with console.log(JSON.stringify(params)); it returns '{}'

Comment: Any idea why the hash is removed before I can access it?