# Angular 2: How do I handle redirect routes to my page with incoming JSON data?

Tags: json, angular, express, passport.js, angular2-routing

I have two problems, I need to be able to redirect users from facebook permissions acceptance from passportjs-facebook and from paypal payments redirect but I don't know how to do this in angular. I need to access posted JSON data coming from my own express server with an angular route which receives and uses that data.

If I do an a href="/auth" login button it sends my user to facebook's page to grant app permissions, after they do it redirects them to /auth/facebook/callback which is a blank white page with this json: {"ok":true,"status":"Login successful","success":true,"token":"...", user: {..}, }. How do I make it so they are redirected back to a page on my angular2 app and that this token is read into a json object within my apps so I can put it in local storage?  This is my backend code:

```
userRouter.get('/auth', passport.authenticate('facebook', {scope: ['public_profile', 'user_friends', 'email']}), (req, res) => {});
userRouter.get('/auth/facebook/callback', function(req,res,next){
  passport.authenticate('facebook', function(err, user, info) {           
    if (err) {
      return next(err);
    }
    if (!user) {
      return res.status(401).json({
        err: info
      });
    }
    req.logIn(user, function(err) {
      if (err) {
        return res.status(500).json({
          err: 'Login failed'
        });
      }
      var token = Verify.getToken(user); 
      res.status(200).json({
        status: 'Login successful',
        success: true,
        token: token
      });
    });
  })(req,res,next);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a `res.redirect` to the URL of one of your Angular pages, and include the token as a query string.

`res.redirect('/#!/myprofile?token=MYTOKEN');` instead of the `res.status(200).json...` code

Alternatively you can parse the query string sent with the redirect right away in Angular as in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39668916/angular2-get-url-query-parameters), but I think that way can be a bit messy. **That example will also help you through accessing query strings in Angular2.**