# How to retrieve parameters from URL fragment in Angular application?

Tags: angular, oauth

I use OAuth Implicit flow authentication method in my Angular application. To retrieve access token I need to parse parameters from following string:

`http://localhost/authentication#access_token={0}&expires_in={1}&user_id={2}`

After some investigation I did not find any mechanisms to retrieve parameters from such URLs (all mechanisms which I found are based on using manual string splitting. Does it mean that Angular doesn't have "out of the box" mechanisms to parse parameters from URL fragment and the best way to do this is use `substring()` or `split()` method?

Comment: constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router) {
this.route
      .queryParams
      .subscribe(params => {
          console.log(params );
      });
}

can you try this in your root component

Comment: @user183101 did you ever resolve this?

Comment: If you want to use fragment with queryParams, it should be like this:
http://localhost/authentication?access_token={0}&expires_in={1}&user_id={2}#fragment_1

Answer (score 5):

You can do it using the `ActivatedRoute` :

```
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.route.snapshot.fragment); // only update on component creation
    this.route.fragment.subscribe(
      (fragments) => console.log(fragments)
    ); // update on all changes
  }
```

To retrieve query parameters, just replace `fragment` by `queryParams` on this code.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, your code won't work for me, because parameters in my URL are in the fragment. See [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47154085/how-to-retrieve-parameters-from-url-fragment-in-angular-application#comment81259864_47154868)

Comment: It works with fragments and queryParams. But your url seems to be wrong, you have &params without the first ?params, so maybe angular can't get the queryParams this way

Comment: URL is correct according to OAuth specification. It seems like Angular can't parse parameters in fragments

Comment: Ok, I see the problem. There is maybe a solution here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36665234/retrieve-hash-fragment-from-url-with-angular2

Answer (score 3):

Maybe it's a bit late, but could help someone in the same situation

With this code you should be able to retrieve the params pretty straightforward

```
this.activatedRoute.fragment.subscribe((fragment: string) => {
    const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(fragment);
    const accessToken = urlParams.get("access_token")
})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {

    const fragment = activatedRoute.snapshot.fragment;

    const parts = fragment.split('&');

    const params = parts.reduce((map, part) => {
        const pieces = part.split('=');
        map[pieces[0]] = pieces[1];
        return map;
    }, {});

    console.log(params);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
import {Router, ActivatedRoute, Params} from '@angular/router';
import {OnInit, Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({...})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    // subscribe to router event
    this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
        let userId = params['user_id'];
        console.log(userId);
      });
  }

}
```

If you want to get the query parameters, replace `this.activatedRoute.params` with `this.activatedRoute.queryParams`.

Comment: Please, see at the URL, which I presented above. As I understand, your solution works for cases without fragments (without symbol '#' in URL). In my case I get 'undefined' in console with your code.

Comment: Okay. Then I think you will have to use the pure javascript method to parse such URL. In Angular, there is no such method to do so. You can see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/40058721/4865392 as well.