# Extracting ACCESS_TOKEN from Instagram redirect with Angular 5(Implicit Authentication)

Tags: angular, typescript, instagram, instagram-api

Since I'm developing a pure frontend app with no backend, I'm going with Instagram implicit authentication. The problem is, after the user authorizes the app, Instagram redirects to my redirect_uri with the access token like this, `http://your-redirect-uri#access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN`. How do I extract the access token from this? I tried using the router but with '#' it was not successful

Comment: Have a look at this question and answers. https://stackoverflow.com/q/39668916/5476757 
And, comment/buzz if it doesn't work. Also, provide more information on what are the URL location strategies you've tried and the code implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Use `window.location.hash` to access to all parameters starting from #.
Or you can use `window.location.href` to access full URL.
To get the token you can use `window.location.hash.match(/#access_token=([^&]+)/)[1]`.

Note: If you are using TypeScript then you'd need to import window in your component.

```
declare let window;
```